# How to select a text in the HTML page only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I need to show the selected text into popup window, okay, I created the popup window and added event handler, for example.

```
$("body").on("click", function(){
    var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString() ;
    myPopupWindow.show(selectedText) ;
})
```

And then I show the text into the popup window, but when I select a text into the popup window it appears again, but I don't want to appear it again when popup is showing.

Comment: Your popup is inside the `body` element, which makes a second click in the popup trigger the code again. Just change your jQuery selection from `body` to the outer most container that you want your users to be able to select text in.

Answer (score 1):

add an `if` statement to check the visibility of your popup:

```
$("body").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#popup").css("display") == "none") {
        var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString() ;
        myPopupWindow.show(selectedText);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

change your $("body") to something more specific like a container div of just the web content, so text selection in the popup doesn't trigger the same action.

Comment: There is a problem i didn't say i create a chrome ext. and i am going to inject my code in all pages which my user will open.